# Regex finding second string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to get the last word in the following strings.

After about 45 minutes I can't seem to find the right combination of slashes, dashes and brackets.

The closest I've got is

`/(?![survey])[a-z]+/gi`

It matches the following strings, except for "required" it is returning the match "quired" I'm assuming it's because the `re` are in the word survey.

```
survey[1][title]
survey[1][required]
survey[2][anotherString]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a *character set*, which will exclude *any* of the characters from being the first character in the match, which isn't what you want. Using plain negative lookahead would be a start:

```
(?!survey)[a-z]+
```

But you also want to match the *final* word, which can be done by matching word characters that are followed with `\]$` - that is, by a `]` and the end of the string:

```
[a-z]+(?=\]$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/rLvsY5/1

If you want to be more efficient, match the *whole string*, but capture what comes between the square brackets in a capturing group - the last repeated captured group will be in the result:

```
survey(?:\[(\w+)\])+
```

https://regex101.com/r/rLvsY5/2

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is to match the full line and only capture the part you need.

```
survey\[\d+\]\[([a-z]+)\]
```